# How to remove unused CSS using Webpack 4 with mini-css-extract-plugin?

Tags: webpack, plugins, purifycss

I was trying to delete unused CSS using Webpack 4.41.5 . I've found that the best for this would be to use PurifyCSS Plugin, but it should run with extract-text-webpack-plugin which is deprecated in WP4^. Can anyone recommend a plugin which will run with mini-css-extract-plugin?
I've recently started using webpack so this topic might seems dumb.
Thank you :)